# Trying to find networking metrics with R

Tags: r, networking, cluster-analysis, igraph

I have created a directed network in R.  I have to find the average degree, which I think I have, the diameter and the maximum/minimum clustering.  The diameter is the longest of the shortest distances between two nodes.  If this makes sense to anyone, please point me in the right direction.  I have what I have coded below so far.

```
library(igraph)

ghw <- graph.formula(1-+4:5:9:12:14, 2-+11:16:17, 3-+4:5:7, 
                     4-+1:3:6:7:8, 5-+1:3:6:7, 6-+4:5:8, 
                     7-+3:4:5:8:13, 8-+4:6:7, 9-+10:12:14:15, 
                     10-+9:12:14, 11-+2:16:17, 12-+1:9:10:14, 
                     13-+7:15:18, 14-+1:9:10:12, 15-+13:16:18, 
                     16-+2:11:15:17:18, 17-+2:11:16:18, 18-+13:15:16:17)
plot(ghw)
get.adjacency(ghw)
```

Total number of directed edges

```
numdeg <- ecount(ghw)
```

Average number of edges per node

```
avgdeg <- numdeg / 18
```

Answer (score 1):

How about looking at the documentation?

```
diameter(ghw)
```

I am not sure what you mean by maximum/minimum clustering, but maybe this:

```
range(transitivity(ghw, type="local"))
```

Btw. your average number of edges per node is wrong, because every edge belongs to two nodes.

Comment: I just started R a couple days ago.  I have been just googling stuff.  I agree, need to look at more documentation.  With the average number of edges, I though each edge would basically count twice.  I thought it would be 1 has 5 edges, 2 has 4 edges etc knowing that 16 having 4 edges may include one from 1 and 2

Comment: This is igraph's R manual: http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/00Index.html If you just search for diameter, or transitivity, you'll get what you want.